# Path for dynamically loading OpenCL.dll?

Tags: opencl

I want to dynamically link OpenCL.dll on the users PC.
When I analyse my own PC I am able to find a lot of OpenCL.dll

```
C:/Windows/SysWOW64
C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/...
C:/Windows/System32
C:/Program Files(x86)/AMD APP SDK /...
```

So I would like to know which is the correct path to load this dll at run time?
Also what is the path for other platforms?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to: IF the user has installed OpenCL, then he has an "installable client driver", and this should be installed into a path that is visible via the `PATH` environment variable. So IF the DLL is available, then it should be visible automatically (unless something went wrong with the installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit machine, you want the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 version.  If you are running a 64-bit executable on a 64-bit machine or a 32-bit executable on a 32-bit machine, you want the C:\Windows\System version.  But I will say that the Windows LoadLibrary call will figure that stuff out for you.  You should just be able to call LoadLibrary(L"OpenCL.dll").  It will pick the right one for you.

The other locations are part of driver or SDK installations that may not be deployed on other systems that have OpenCL.

Comment: Agreed. You should not specify the path, just load the DLL and the OS will find it in the right place.

Comment: @boiler96 Thanks for the answer and Dithermaster for your conformance.